# Various profiles and settings in H264 AVC codec

Tags: video, ffmpeg, h.264, codec, mediainfo

When I convert a video with `ffmpeg`, and use `mediaInfo` to review the metadata, I see the followings for the video codec:

```
Format : AVC 
Format/Info : Advanced Video Codec 
Format profile : Baseline@L3.1 
Format settings : 1 Ref Frames
```

Whereas for some other videos, `mediaInfo` shows this:

```
Format : AVC 
Format/Info : Advanced Video Codec 
Format profile : High@L4.2 
Format settings : CABAC / 4 Ref Frames
```

What are the differences between these two profiles and settings? Do they have any effects on the compression ratio/file sizes? Any pros/cons? My goal is to reduce the video file sizes at much as possible with negligible quality degradation.

Comment: Wikipedia has [the descriptions of the h.264 profiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Video_Coding#Profiles)

Comment: In case of `High` vs. `Baseline` the former is more computationally intensive but allows for more efficient compression and quality for a target bitrate.

Comment: @aergistal how about decoding side? Any difference on decoding?

Answer (score 0):

AVC can be described as set of features.
The AVC profiles (Baseline or High) are a list of allowed features for the profile.
The more features - the better is the compression.
For example High supports B-frames and Baseline doesn't.

A higher profile requires more resources for encoding and decoding - compute and memory.

So you are trading file size (or quality) for RAM and processing.
I am guessing for most PC and newer smartphone applications - you are better off using a higher AVC profile.
For some embedded application - your hardware may not support higher profiles.
If latency for live streaming needs to be low - you may want to avoid B-frames.

Nowadays - Main and High are pretty common and give you a quality or file size advantage.